# Exporting and Importing .csv files using a script

Tags: php, csv, calendar, mamp, icalendar

Hi I have a MAMP server set up on a mac I am using and I have this displaying a calendar using the php icalendar source code. I am trying to have this display a public calendar which I can do but I need it to be up to date so I need it to import the Calendars csv file regularly. So my question is does anyone know how I could go about programmatically exporting a .csv file from a public calendar and how I could then import it into a certain location on a server again via a script or code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to download the .csv file.

You could use fopen, cURL to download the file. For fopen you need to enable to read files from an url.

An other way, must be supported by the other party. Is to use ftp.

I think the best way for these is just look at php.net how to let them work.

Second you want to make a scheduld job. I don't know it in macs, but with linux you can make cron's you can say these need to be run every x time (1min, 1day 1 week).

In the script you do the download and update part.

Hope it helps